# How to convert single line json to multi-line json? tried with circe got undesirable results

Tags: json, scala

sample code

```
val json =
    """{"k1":"v1","kl":[1,2,3]}""".stripMargin
  val parsed = parse(json) match {
    case Left(failure) =>
    case Right(json) =>
      println(json.noSpaces)
      println(json.spaces2)
  }
```

got output(spaces2)

```
{
  "k1" : "v1",
  "kl" : [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

desired output format

```
{
  "k1" : "v1",
  "kl" : [1,2,3]
}
```

I can use any other library as well if it works.

Comment: What is the problem in such multiline json?

Comment: I need the one like the format I wrote

Answer (score 0):

You have options:

1. find and use a library that will do what you want
2. implement a pretty printer by yourself. I think you can google a few examples - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/writing-json-pretty-printer-kurt-cagle/
3. implement correction function and use it for current output